# reading in many tables from SQLlite databases and combining in R

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr, union, rsqlite

I'm working with a program that outputs a database of results. I have hundreds of these databases that are all identical in structure and I'd like to combine them into ONE big database. I'm mostly interested in 1 table from each database. I don't work with databases/sql very much, but it would simplify other steps in the process, to skip outputting a csv.

Previously I did this by exporting a csv and used these steps to combine all csvs:

### Vector of all CSVs & combine

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)

csv_locs<- list.files(newdir, recursive = TRUE, pattern="*.csv", full.names = TRUE)

pic_dat <- do.call("rbind", lapply(csv_locs, 
FUN=function(files){data.table::fread(files, data.table = FALSE)}))
```

### How to do this with sql type database tables??

I'm basically pulling out the first table, then joining on the rest with a loop.

```
db_locs <- list.files(directory, recursive = TRUE, pattern="*.ddb", full.names = TRUE)


# first table
con1<- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), db_locs [1])
start <- tbl(con1, "DataTable")

# open connection to location[i], get table, union, disconnect; repeat. 
for(i in 2:length(db_locs )){
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), db_locs[i])
y <- tbl(con, "DataTable")
start <- union(start, y, copy=TRUE)
dbDisconnect(con)
}
```

#### This is exceptionally slow! Well, to be fair, its large data and the csv one is also slow.

I think I honestly wrote the slowest possible way to do this :) I could not get the do.call/lapply option to work here, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks similar to *"iterative `rbind`ing of frames"*, in that each time you do this `union`, it will copy the entire table into a new object (unconfirmed, but that's my gut feeling). This might work well for a few but scales very poorly. I suggest you collect all tables in a list and call `data.table::rbindlist` *once* at the end, then insert into a table.

Without your data, I'll contrive a situation. And because I'm not entirely certain if you have just one table per sqlite3 file, I'll add two tables per database. If you only have one, the solution simplifies easily.

```r
for (i in 1:3) {
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), sprintf("mtcars_%d.sqlite3", i))
  DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mt1", mtcars[1:3,1:3])
  DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mt2", mtcars[4:5,4:7])
  DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
}
(lof <- list.files(pattern = "*.sqlite3", full.names = TRUE))
# [1] "./mtcars_1.sqlite3" "./mtcars_2.sqlite3" "./mtcars_3.sqlite3"
```

Now I'll iterate over each them and read the contents of a table

```r
allframes <- lapply(lof, function(fn) {
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), fn)
  mt1 <- tryCatch(DBI::dbReadTable(con, "mt1"),
                  error = function(e) NULL)
  mt2 <- tryCatch(DBI::dbReadTable(con, "mt2"),
                  error = function(e) NULL)
  DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
  list(mt1 = mt1, mt2 = mt2)
})
allframes
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$mt1
#    mpg cyl disp
# 1 21.0   6  160
# 2 21.0   6  160
# 3 22.8   4  108
# [[1]]$mt2
#    hp drat    wt  qsec
# 1 110 3.08 3.215 19.44
# 2 175 3.15 3.440 17.02
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$mt1
#    mpg cyl disp
# 1 21.0   6  160
# 2 21.0   6  160
# 3 22.8   4  108
### ... repeated
```

From here, just combine them in R and write to a new database. While you can use `do.call(rbind,...)` or `dplyr::bind_rows`, you already mentioned `data.table` so I'll stick with that:

```r
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "mtcars_all.sqlite3")
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mt1", data.table::rbindlist(lapply(allframes, `[[`, 1)))
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mt2", data.table::rbindlist(lapply(allframes, `[[`, 2)))
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select count(*) as n from mt1")
#   n
# 1 9
DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
```

In the event that you can't load them all into R at one time, then append them to the table in real-time:

```r
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "mtcars_all2.sqlite3")
for (fn in lof) {
  con2 <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), fn)
  mt1 <- tryCatch(DBI::dbReadTable(con2, "mt1"), error = function(e) NULL)
  if (!is.null(mt1)) DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mt1", mt1, append = TRUE)
  mt2 <- tryCatch(DBI::dbReadTable(con2, "mt2"), error = function(e) NULL)
  if (!is.null(mt1)) DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mt2", mt2, append = TRUE)
  DBI::dbDisconnect(con2)
}
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select count(*) as n from mt1")
#   n
# 1 9
```

This doesn't suffer the iterative-slowdown that you're experiencing.

Comment: hi! I'm working on getting this to run (some errors that I'm trying to understand/fix), but this looks like a fantastic solution. I've just been swamped and need to get to this!

Comment: Thanks, this totally works & is WAY faster than my snowballing-loop! Now I just need to get comfortable with the database-instead-of-dataframe... but that's a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [`ATTACH`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to create schemas for the databases you import from:

```r
library(DBI)

file1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".sqlite")
file2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".sqlite")

con1 <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = file1)
con2 <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = file2)

dbWriteTable(con1, "iris", iris[1:3, ])
dbWriteTable(con2, "iris", iris[4:6, ])

# Main connection
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbExecute(con, paste0("ATTACH '", file1, "' AS con1"))
#> [1] 0
dbExecute(con, paste0("ATTACH '", file2, "' AS con2"))
#> [1] 0

dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM con1.iris UNION ALL SELECT * FROM con2.iris")
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>